# Is there software that help me pre-visualize photowall collage before I commit to hanging the photos?

Tags: prints, software-recommendation, collage

I have around 10 8x10, 100 4x6 (few portrait and few landscape) printed photos. I would like to create a photowall using these pictures. However, would like to put these pictures in a tool and want it to create a collage for me and want to see how it looks before putting them on wall.

Is there any tool / website for this ?

Comment: Reference: Ex: https://goo.gl/dLCV1F

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any tool / website for this ?

Any image editing program (e.g. Photoshop) would work. Take a picture of your wall, import it, and superimpose miniature versions of the photos you're going to hang. Make the process quicker by creating guidelines to help you keep the photos properly positioned as you switch them around.

Comment: Any demo / tutorial on this will help. Thank You !